# Python add last row and column of 2darray to last positions - Polar Contour plot

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I created a polar contour plot and try to close it by adding the data of first row to the end.
See in this picture at 180 deg:
[PolarPlot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWFyU.png)

Data is created by using meshgrid and griddata modules.
The array sizes are of nxn type.
In example:
ri - float64 - (100,100) size

```
print ri 
    [[ 0.00160738  0.00184056  0.00207375 ...,  0.23409252  0.23432571
   0.23455889]
 [ 0.00160738  0.00184056  0.00207375 ...,  0.23409252  0.23432571
   0.23455889]
 [ 0.00160738  0.00184056  0.00207375 ...,  0.23409252  0.23432571
   0.23455889]
```

theta and contour is created equivalent.

Plotting is done by matplotlib

How can I do this? Is this the right way for "closing" the plot at 180 degrees?

And here is the plot snippet:

```
fig4 = plt.figure()
ax = fig4.add_subplot(111)
ax = plt.axes(polar=True)
image=plt.contourf(thetai,ri/d,contourd,128,vmin=0,extent=([-math.pi,+math.pi,min(ri[0]/d),max(ri[0]/d)]),cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

ax.set_xlabel(r'$\Theta$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$r$')
```

Comment: Please show the code that does the actual plotting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not really become clear from your question what your data looks like. 
In general though, for polar plots to be closed, the last point of your data has to be the same as the first. So if you have an array `X` where `X[:,0]` is the angle and `X[:,1]` is the radius, you can close the polar plot by appending the first element to the end like so:

```
X_closed = np.append(X,X[[0]],axis = 0)
```

I.e. you only have to add the first row to the end, not the first column.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer,
my problem is that I have interpolated the data on a 2d mesh before, so
radius is an 100x100 array and theta an 100x100.array. My contour consists also of 100x100 elements.
After trying your "append" snippet I got always 101x100 elements and the plot is still "open"

Comment: Ok, so the weird circular *hole* in your plot looks like it is not just a matter of *closing* the contour by adding another column. What does the data look like if you plot the contours without the polar projection?

Comment: Solved it, the data was missing by extrapolating the field solution, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about your exact plot, but you can perform the array operation you describe using [`numpy.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

We can give `np.pad` your original array, and a `pad_width` of `((0,1),(0,1))`, which means pad 0 columns on the left, 1 on the right, 0 columns on top, and 1 on the bottom. Set `mode='edge'` to copy the values on the edge of the array.

For example:

```
In [16]: a = np.array([[1,1,5],[2,2,6],[7,8,9]])
In [17]: a
Out[17]: 
array([[1, 1, 5],
       [2, 2, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [18]: np.pad(a,((0,1),(0,1)),mode='edge')
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 1, 5, 5],
       [2, 2, 6, 6],
       [7, 8, 9, 9],
       [7, 8, 9, 9]])
```